# Visual Studio Compiling Cl doesn't interpret whitespace?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to add CL (MSVC) to my sys env and executable directories, but an error pops up that is seperating the paths by whitespace.

````
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication10, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Program
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\Program': No such file or directory
1>Microsoft
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Files\Microsoft': No such file or directory
1>Visual
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Visual': No such file or directory
1>x64
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\Hostx64\x64': No such file or directory
1>ConsoleApplication10.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\yvals.h(12,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication10.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========```
````

Comment: put your paths in double quotes

Comment: I tried that with ```"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe";```, but if i do i get ```Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication10, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication10.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========``` @doug

Comment: You seem to be having a lot of problems with visual studio. What exactly are you trying to do? Have you tried reinstalling visual studio?

Comment: Regarding the C1083 error, I suggest you watch this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1083?view=msvc-170), which contains the cause and solution of the C1083 error.

Comment: i got it fixed! thanks!